# (using Visual Studio 2013) How to call a Stored Procedure inside an oracle package with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have tried to add oracle procedures that placed inside the package using EF5 with ADO.NET Entity Data Model and nothing get imported. I cannot see any procedures.

I am using ODAC 12c Release 3 - > Oracle Data Provide.

I can import procedures that created outside the package.

Our development standard is to use oracle packages to define procedures. I am now moving from VS2008 to VS2013 with Entity Framework.

Please advise and provide possible solutions to overcome this problem. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did something similar in a recent project. Note that I use DevArt instead of ODAC, but perhaps you'll find some inspiration here to solve your issue.

I first created a class that held all parameters required for the function:

```
public class MyFunctionParameter
{
    public DateTime? MyDateTime { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

This class also contained a ToOracleParameters() method. Note that [OracleParameter is from DevArt](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleParameter.html):

```
public List<OracleParameter> ToOracleParameters()
{
    return new List<OracleParameter>
    {
        new OracleParameter("My_Date_Time", OracleDbType.Date, MyDateTime, ParameterDirection.Input),
        new OracleParameter("Source", OracleDbType.VarChar, Source, ParameterDirection.Input),
        new OracleParameter("ID", OracleDbType.Number, ParameterDirection.Output)
    };
}
```

In my method I then used this class like this:

```
var parameters = parameter.ToOracleParameters();
var inParameterList = string.Join(", ", 
    parameters.Where(x => x.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input)
        .Select(x => ":" + x.ParameterName));
var outParameter = parameters.Single(x => x.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output);
var sql = string.Format("BEGIN :{0} := MY_ORACLE_FUNCTION({1}); end;", 
    outParameter.ParameterName, inParameterList);

DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<object>(sql, parameters.Cast<object>().ToArray()).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do the following:

1. In Server Explorer-->Data connections you will see the connection you have made to generate your model. You can modify the connection from there. There is a Tab called Filter, from where you can set many objects you can see. For example, you can get the public synonyms and displayed collections (packages, views, tables, etc)
2. I am not an Oracle expert, but, can you create a public synonym for a procedure wich is inside a package? Probably it would work
3. If you cannot find a solution, you can go here:
   https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/windows_and_.net

Some of the guys who have developed the Entity Framework for Oracle probably will help you.

Hope it helps.

Regards